# Convert dictionary to Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, list, dictionary

I am using the following ASP MVC code to convert a dictionary to a JsonResult

```
public JsonResult docGet()
{
    ......

    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (ListItem ListItem in collListItem)
    {
        dictionary.Add((ListItem["ID"], ListItem["Title"]);     
        }

return Json(Result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This code is not working. The result is []. If I change dictionary type to list with only 1 value it is working. But the desired result is a Key Value Pair List in json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main reason you are getting an empty result is because you are returning `Result`, not the `dictionary` variable that you populated.

Aditionally, if collListItem is `IEnumerable<ListItem>` (as it seems to be, since you are looping through it with foreach), you don't need to build the dictionary item by item.

Try:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictionary=collListItem.ToDictionary(c=>c["ID"],c=>c["Title"]);

return Json(dictionary,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```